# Using calculation field in lower Row. something like Running Total

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, cumulative-sum

I have a table with the following structure:

1) RowNo

2) BillValue

3) Balance

4) X = (my calculated field)

A filled version of the table is showed below:

```
RowNo  BillValue  Balance  X
1                 9689454  9689454
2      812,500    8876954  8876954
3      741,343    8135611  8135611
4      838,430    7297181  7297181
5      1,297,151  6000030  6000030
6      1,425,398  6648632  4574632
7      1,022,478  5626154  3552154
8      587,560    5038594  2964594
9      674,655    4363939  2289939
10     355,005    4008934  1934934
11     1,113,673  2895261  821261
12     759,961    2135300  61300
13     61,300     1271654  0
```

First “X” value = Balance (I call it X1 which means x filed with RowNo = 1)

`X2 = X1 – BillValue`

`X3 = X2 – BillValue`

And finally: `X(n) = X(n-1) – BillValue`

The questions remind me Running Total. However, it is different one.
Please consider that by joining the table by itself, and using some query like below:

```
FROM 
    C1
LEFT JOIN
    C1 C2 ON C1.RowNo = C2.RowNo + 1
```

We are calculating the all x in first step which is wrong. X has to be move to lower row after calculation.

What’s the best way without using cursor in SQL Server 2012 and higher versions?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1:**  Added StdID as per the comments

**EDIT 2:**  Modified script to always use first value of Balance instead of MAX

This can be done using below script without any joins:

```
CREATE TABLE #Order(
    StdID INT,
    RowNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    BillValue NUMERIC(10,2),
    Balance NUMERIC(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO #Order(StdID,BillValue,Balance)
VALUES
(1,0,1000),
(1,500,1200),
(1,100,900),
(1,200,700),
(1,100,600),
(2,0,2000),
(2,1000,1200),
(2,500,2500),
(2,400,700),
(2,100,600)

SELECT  StdID,
        RowNo,
        BillValue,
        Balance,
        (FIRST_VALUE(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY STDID ORDER BY RowNo)-SUM(BillValue) OVER(PARTITION BY STDID ORDER BY RowNo)) AS X
FROM #Order;

DROP TABLE #Order;
```

Comment: That is a good idea to use LAG and LEAD. However, here in this case first X value remains NULL that means wrong value for X1.

Comment: What value do you expect for first X1?

Comment: Plz check updated ans to show Balance for X1 using ISNULL.

Comment: It is good, still has an error in case all Balance value is ordered DESC.

Comment: It is good, still has an error in case all Balance value is ordered DESC.
If the 3rd value was like this (200, 1100) that wouldn't work correctly.

Secondly, I need to run this quer over a table which has stID. That means for each stID I need its result

Comment: To populate result for each StdID, you can you PARTITION BY StdID in MAX and SUM functions. I didn't get your point on error in the code if Balance is DESC. Please elaborate.

Comment: imagine balances like this:
VALUES
(0,1000),
(500,1000),
(100,900),
(200,1200),
(100,600)

In that case we face wrong calculation. because 1200 has higher value.

Comment: @AliElmi Please check updated ans which always uses first value of Balance order by RowNo. This also includes how to get results for each StdID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.RowNo, t1.BillValue, t1.Balance,
       t2.Balance - SUM(t1.BillValue) OVER (ORDER BY RowNo) AS X
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Balance FROM mytable WHERE RowNo = 1) AS t2
```

The `CROSS JOIN` operation is used in order to obtain the `Balance` value of the initial row. Using this value, we can calculate field `X` by subtracting the *running total* of field `BillValue`. The running total can be easily calculated using the window version of function `SUM` with `ORDER BY` clause. This version of `SUM` is available from SQL Server 2012 onward.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bills](
    RowNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    BillValue int NOT NULL,
    Balance int NOT NULL
)
```

Then create view

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.BillsX
AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, Balance as X, 1 as lev
    FROM dbo.Bills
    WHERE RowNo = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.*, (LAG(c.X,0,0) OVER (ORDER BY lev))- b.BillValue, lev+1 
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN dbo.Bills b
        ON b.RowNo = c.RowNo +1
)

SELECT  RowNo,
        BillValue,
        Balance,
        X
FROM cte
```